# GmailApp.sendEmail() Add custom "From" to email body

Tags: google-apps-script

I have this code from google script i use it to send a notification to my coworkers each time someone submits a form for the company.

```
function LeadNotifier(e) {

 var values = e.values;
  var htmlBody = '<div background:#E5E8E8;><h2 style="color:#154360;">MENSSAJE WEB <h2><ul>';
  for (var i=0; i < values.length; i++) {

    var data = values[i];
    var replyto = values[2];
    htmlBody += '<li>' + ": " + data + '</li>';

  };
  htmlBody += '</ul><h3 ><strong style="color:green;" >Web Site:</strong> company name </h3></div>';
  GmailApp.sendEmail('dev@mycompany.com','QUOTE REQUEST','',{htmlBody:htmlBody,replyTo: replyto});



}
```

Working good so far, but  when i get the emails on the "from" field takes the email of the form creator, i want to put the name of the user in there

currently, they get the email like this

```
|  subject     |        from          |    
|QUOTE REQUEST | form_admin@gmail.com |
```

I need to get them like this

```
|  subject     |        from          |    
|QUOTE REQUEST |     jhon Doe         |
```

y checked the [Documents](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient-subject-body-options)  and found  a parameter called "from" but when i use it it gives me this error.

```
ERRORInvalid argument: Arya Stark  at LeadNotifier(Code:13)
```

So i think i'm using it the wrong way i'm putting it like this

```
var user_name = "Arya Stark"
  GmailApp.sendEmail('dev@mycompany.com','QUOTE REQUEST','',{htmlBody:htmlBody,replyTo: replyto, 'from':user_name});
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: I can't help you without seeing e.values? Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GMailApp only allows you to use your own email address or an alias address linked with your account. This is to prevent people from acting like someone else by putting other people's addresses in the `from` field.

Answer (score 0):

I need to see your data.

This might help you to figure it out:

```
function LeadNotifier(e) {
  var e=e || {values:['0','1','2','3','4','5','6']};
  var values = e.values;
  var replyto = values[2];
  var html = '<div><h2 style="color:#154360;">MENSSAJE WEB </h2><ul>';
  for (var i=0;i<values.length;i++) {
    var data=values[i];
    html+=Utilities.formatString('<li>values[%s]=%s</li>',i,values[i])
    //html += '<li>'+": "+data+'</li>';

  };
  html += '</ul><h3 ><strong style="color:green;" >Web Site:</strong> company name </h3></div>';
  //GmailApp.sendEmail('dev@mycompany.com','QUOTE REQUEST','',{htmlBody:html,replyTo: replyto});
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html)
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, 'Test'); 
}
```